# The method servletContext.addServlet in the type ServletContext is not applicable for the arguments (String, DispatcherServlet)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am building spring maven project with spring 4.2.5 in order to create simple login java web application using Spring MVC, Spring Security and Spring JDBC but I am getting compile time error in:

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
```

the error says:

> The method addServlet(String, String) in the type ServletContext is not applicable for the arguments (String, DispatcherServlet)

I am already using javax.servlet version 3.1.0 
pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.archmage</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVCAnnotationSecurity</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringMVCAnnotationSecurity Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <!-- generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
    <javax.servlet.jsp.version>2.2</javax.servlet.jsp.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.34</mysql.version>
    <ojdbc.version>11.2.0.3</ojdbc.version>
    <jtds.version>1.3.1</jtds.version>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
    <repository>
        <id>codelds</id>
        <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring framework START -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring framework END -->
    <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - START -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - END -->
    <!-- Jstl for jsp page -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSP API -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet.jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${ojdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SQLServer JDBC driver (JTDS) -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>${jtds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCAnnotationSecurity</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Config: Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

SpringWebAppInitializer.java:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

Any idea why the method `addServlet` in the `ServletContext` is not applicable for second argument for the type of `DispatcherServlet` ?

---

So the method 
[addServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet(java.lang.String,%20javax.servlet.Servlet)) only accept `Servlet` class as its second parameter?

Comment: Try clean and rebuild?

Comment: I already tried to clean and rebuild / restart eclipse but the error still exist

Comment: @Rival it can accept any class which implements servlet interface, and DispatcherServlet implements it so it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In below code :

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
```

you are using `appContext`.

Create DispatcherServlet's Spring application context and then give that value.

For ex. add below code :

```
// Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
```

This should work.